# Passing a vector to data.table with index in R

Tags: r, data.table

How can I subset `iris_dt`using the vector `subz` and achieve the same results as the line above

```
library(data.table)

iris_dt <- data.table(iris)
setindex(iris_dt, Sepal.Length)
setindex(iris_dt, Species)



iris_dt[.(6.7, 'virginica'), on = c('Sepal.Length', 'Species')]

subz <- c(6.7, 'virginica')
```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: I want to subset iris_dt using  the vector subz

Comment: `subz <- data.table(6.7, 'virginica');
iris_dt[subz, on=c('Sepal.Length'="V1", 'Species'="V2")]` BTW: in `subz <- c(6.7, 'virginica')` the value `6.7` is coerced to a character `"6.7"`.

Comment: @jogo thanks, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set key, and avoid using `c` because of data type coercion.

```
setkey(iris_dt, Sepal.Length, Species)
subz <- list(6.7, 'virginica')
iris_dt[subz]
```